# kotlin / java - Is there something like TryParse()?

Tags: java, kotlin

I need to convert 3 editText to Double and do an automatic calculation. The problem is: in Java, using `Double.parseDouble()` throw an exception if editText string is null so I have to use a try catch. In Kotlin, using `toDoubleOrNull` I have to check with an "if" if is null or not.

Now, with 2 editText i have to do `val a = firstDobule + secondDouble` and then `val b = a + 2`
But using aboved methods I can't separate the calculation: it need to convert all 3 editText in the same time and I want to convert a singular editText at time.

to make you understand better, this is the code in C#:

```
 Double.TryParse(firstEditText.Text, out Double firstDouble);
 Double.TryParse(secondEditText.Text, out Double secondDOuble);

Double a = firstDouble + secondDOuble;
Double b = a + 2;
```

In C#, using TryParse it doesn't throw any exception and doesn't need to check manually if is null or not. 
I want to do this, but in Kotlin or Java

Comment: You don't even need a Try/Catch do you?  Just check for null.

Comment: Using Try Catch or checking if null, it need to convert all 3 editText in the same time and, as I said, I need to convert a singular editText at time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write an extension function for `EditText` that will return its text value as a double.

```
fun EditText.doubleValue() = text.toString().toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
```

This assumes you want to get 0 in case of unparsable input. Then you can read off values easily:

```
val a = firstEditText.doubleValue() + secondEditText.doubleValue()
val b = a + 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think @Pawel is on the right track, however, I'd define an [extension property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-properties) instead of an extension function, as it seems to be more appropriate semantically:

```
val EditText.doubleValue: Double
    get() = text.toString().toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
```

The usage would then look like this:

```
val a = firstEditText.doubleValue + secondEditText.doubleValue
val b = a + 2
```

Comment: With val it gives me error, using fun it works perfectly